# What does `avahi-dnsconfd` daemon?

Tags: arch-linux, daemon, avahi

I've installed **KDE** desktop, that depends on **avahi**. It has two daemons `avahi-daemon` and `avahi-dnsconfd`.

In ArchLinux wiki there is no info about `avahi-dnsconfd`. I've tried [Daemon](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Daemon) and [Avahi](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Avahi) pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the description from debian's avahi-dnsconfd package:

```
Package: avahi-dnsconfd
Description-en: Avahi DNS configuration tool
 Avahi is a fully LGPL framework for Multicast DNS Service Discovery.
 It allows programs to publish and discover services and hosts
 running on a local network with no specific configuration. For
 example you can plug into a network and instantly find printers to
 print to, files to look at and people to talk to.
 .
 This tool listens on the network for announced DNS servers and passes
 them to resolvconf so it can use them. This is very useful on autoconfigured
 IPv6 networks.
Homepage: http://avahi.org/
```

More info should be available at the [Avahi](http://avahi.org/) home page.

Answer (score 1):

`avahi-dnsconfd` is a simple daemon which queries avahi-daemon for addresses of DNS servers. Based on the response it then updates `/etc/resolv.conf` file. Basically:

1. Upon starting it [sends "BROWSE-DNS-SERVERS" request](https://github.com/lathiat/avahi/blob/d1e71b320d96d0f213ecb0885c8313039a09f693/avahi-dnsconfd/main.c#L346) to `avahi-daemon` via `/var/run/avahi-daemon/socket`. Equivalent to:

   ```
   $ echo 'BROWSE-DNS-SERVERS-IPV4' | nc -U /var/run/avahi-daemon/socket
   ```
2. [Waits for the response/update](https://github.com/lathiat/avahi/blob/d1e71b320d96d0f213ecb0885c8313039a09f693/avahi-dnsconfd/main.c#L469) from `avahi-daemon` on the socket. The response string will look something like this:

   ```
   > 3 1 194.168.8.100 53
   > 3 1 194.168.4.100 53
   > 3 0 194.168.8.100 53
   > 3 0 194.168.4.100 53
   ```

   - column 1 indicates new server (>) or server that has been removed (<)
   - column 2 is a numerical network interface ID
   - column 3 is a numerical protocol ID (1=IPv6, 0=IPv4)
   - columns 4 and 5 are the address and port number of the DNS server
3. [For each line of the above response/update](https://github.com/lathiat/avahi/blob/d1e71b320d96d0f213ecb0885c8313039a09f693/avahi-dnsconfd/main.c#L527), executes [`/etc/avahi/dnsconfd.action`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/avahi-dnsconfd.action) script. This script updates `/etc/resolv.conf` file
4. GOTO 2.

For this to work, you need to set `publish-resolv-conf-dns-servers=yes` in `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`

`avahi-dnsconfd` daemon is [normally not used](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/avahi/2011-June/002052.html). Often, `/etc/resolv.conf` file is populated by a DHCP client which obtains DNS addresses from a DHCP Server.

Comment: In other words use mDNS multicasts to configure DNS on the local machine?